# Obiee 12c export service instance command

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, obiee

I am trying to export a .bar file to get backup of the Obiee catalog, when use the WLST export command for this operation i got the below message

**   ERROR! This API is NOT supported anymore.                                              **
**   NOTE: Please use the new related API script under <BI_DOMAIN_HOME>/bitools/bin         **

I need to find the usage of the export_service_instance.cmdç I examined the documents to find the usage of this .cmd file but i can not run the command. Do you have any idea about that

Thank you.

Comment: It would help to have a precise version information. Like 12.2.1.4.200414. "12c" means about 30 different versions.

Comment: 12.2.1.4.31178877 is my version.

Comment: Check this Doc ID 2463087.1 on Oracle Support. Unfortunately, I cannot share details because of Oracle's copyright statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem some time ago.
Actually the mechanism has changed through 12.2.1.3 to 12.2.1.4 . It means that there is no longer WLST command or tool in latest version, instead you have been provided with a bash script file named 'export_service_instance.sh' which should use to fulfill your goal.

you can find this bash file in following path:

..../user_projects/domains/bi/bitools/bin

In addition, The export_service_instance.sh script takes the following parameters:

1. **service key** - the service instance is typically ssi
2. **bar location** - the location where the bar file should be created
3. **[excludes]** which is a comma separated list of nouserfolders and/or noconnectioncredentials where nouserfolders indicates that user folders will be excluded from the generated BAR file and noconnectioncredentials indicates that repository connection credentials will be excluded from the generated BAR file.

You can find more information in [here](http://www.elffar.co.uk/blog/obiee-12213-deprecated-bar-file-apis)